# Don't append item from object to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
for (key in data.rating) {
    current.find('.ratings').append("<div class='single-rating'><p>" + translateRating(language, key) + "<span class='right bold'>" +  data.rating[key]/10 + "</span></p><div class='bar-wrapper'><div class='bar' style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></div></div></div>");
}
```

and a data object structure like that:

```
"rating":{
"overall": 89,
"atmosphere": 82,
"cleanliness": 91,
"facilities": 86,
"staff": 94,
"security": 91,
"location": 91,
"valueForMoney": 90
},
```

as you can see I am appending these in a list of DIVs, I don't need to append overall which is the first one. How do not append it with the rest of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to just add a simple condition in the loop

```
for (key in data.rating) 
{
    if ( key != "overall" )
    {
        current.find('.ratings').append("<div class='single-rating'><p>" + translateRating(language, key) + "<span class='right bold'>" +  data.rating[key]/10 + "</span></p><div class='bar-wrapper'><div class='bar' style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></div></div></div>");
    }
}
```

If we want to avoid this condition, then we can simply delete this key before loop and add it back after loop

```
var overall = data.rating["overall"];
delete data.rating["overall"];
for (key in data.rating) 
{
    current.find('.ratings').append("<div class='single-rating'><p>" + translateRating(language, key) + "<span class='right bold'>" +  data.rating[key]/10 + "</span></p><div class='bar-wrapper'><div class='bar' style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></div></div></div>");
}
data.rating["overall"] = overall;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (key in data.rating) {
  unless(key == "overall"){
    current.find('.ratings').append("<div class='single-rating'><p>" + translateRating(language, key) + "<span class='right bold'>" +  data.rating[key]/10 + "</span></p><div class='bar-wrapper'><div class='bar' style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></div></div></div>");
  }
}
```

Comment: have you got a link for documentation for the `unless` function?